# Tile Searching (Nested For Loops)

Tags: java, performance, for-loop

I'm searching over a tile array so basically have x and y - say for example a 10 by 10 grid. Currently I am using a nested for loop over x and y, but I am wondering since I don't know much about algorithmic design in Java, is there a faster way to do this? Each tile I go to (xn,yn) where n is the tile number, I perform an operation on.

Or is this the fastest way to do this?

Comment: It depends. Is there some transient relationship between the values in the array, or are you simply cycling through each value? What are you intending to do with the values?

Comment: This wreaks of [premature optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize).  Worry about it when the app. slows down visibly.

Comment: Develop > Run > Profile > Decide. You want your code to run before it can walk...

Comment: I guess that is reasonable - I mean the only improvement I could see since this is inside of a function is if I was multitasking it but that would probably make the code unnecessarily complex as you have all pointed out, so I'll leave it as is, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are doing something like this:

```
Tile[][] matrix = new Tile[10][10];

//Some code to initialize matrix

for(int x = 0; x < matrix.length; x ++){
    Tile[] row = matrix[x];
    for(int y = 0; y < row.length; x ++){
        Tile cell = row[y];
        //Perform the 'operation' on cell
    }
}
```

If that is the case then the above code would be O(n^2) * O('operation'). This follows because accessing elements of an array is O(1).

If instead you had Lists instead of arrays then you should write the code like:

```
List<List<Tile>> matrix;

//Some code to initialize matrix

for(List<Tile> row : matrix){
    for(Tile cell : row){
        //Perform the 'operation' on cell
    }
}
```

This implicitly uses the Iterator provided by the List. For example if the List is an ArrayList the iterator will function much the same as the first example. If the List is a LinkedList the iterator will store a reference to the node in the list currently being operated over. For both the vase of the LinkedList and the ArrayList the complexity remains: O(n^2) * O('operation')

Code that would be BAD is:

```
LinkedList<LinkedList<Tile>> matrix = new LinkedList<LinkedList<Tile>>();

//Some code to initialize matrix

for(int x = 0; x < matrix.size(); x ++){
    LinkedList<Tile> row = matrix.get(x);
    for(int y = 0; y < row.size(); x ++){
        Tile cell = row.get(y);
        //Perform the 'operation' on cell
    }
}
```

This example would be  O(n^4) * O('operation') because each call to LinkedList.get(x) is O(n) .Remember the same operation on an array or an ArrayList is O(1).

Comment: the two ways above are the same, in each way there is an iterator, 
in the first one the iterator is an index, and in the second one there is a list iterator.. so it's the same, even the complexity is the same because of the iterator/index

Comment: I am unsure as to which two blocks of code you are referring to. If you are referring to the first two blocks, then yes. As I said, both are O(n^2). If you are referring to the second two blocks of code then you are mistaken. A get operator on a LinkedList is O(n) where as .next() on an iterator from a LinkedList or an ArrayList is O(1). If you don't believe me take a look at the code. The 3rd block of code is the slowest of any of the above blocks.